# Pick First Valid Value and Append As New Column to GroupBy

Tags: mysql, sql

I have many rows with the same data but one or two columns are different.

I would like to reduce the number of rows by merging them together on common data then pull the data that is different into a new column. Also some rows will be missing the common data, but as long as one of the rows has a value for the Order_ID(and Type) it can take that value.

Can be seen better below

---

Raw Data(Jobs):

```
Order_ID Type CreatedTime
5 Collect 1000000000
5 Deliver 
5 Deliver 1100000000
8 Collect 2000000000
8 Collect 2000000000
8 Deliver 2300000000
```

Desired:

```
Order_ID CollectCreatedTime DeliverCreatedTime
5 1000000000 1100000000
8 2000000000 2300000000
```

What I have is this:

```
SELECT Order_ID, SOMETHING() As CollectCreatedTime, SOMETHING() As DeliverCreatedTime
FROM `Jobs` GROUP BY `Order_ID`
```

However I cannot figure out how to "pick the first value that exists(or none if no values exist) and append that to the GROUP BY selection."

Please advise if I need to exist the question to explain it better.

Comment: Well, "Can be seen better below" isn't how I find it.

Comment: When you say first value that exists, do you mean something like MIN() ?

Comment: Sorry I was trying to format it into something similar to a table and it didn't work, please refresh

Comment: @GregViers Yes, where the Order_ID and Type are the same, the CreatedTime will either be Null or the same value each time, and I only need one correct value or no value if there are no correct values

Comment: The ORDER BY in the sub-query makes no sense. You can remove it. Actually, a sub-query isn't needed, simply select directly from Jobs.

Comment: @jarlh Okay that has been updated on the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you want *conditional aggregation*:

```
SELECT Order_ID,
   min(case when Type = 'Collect' then CreatedTime end) as CollectCreatedTime,
   min(case when Type = 'Deliver' then CreatedTime end) as DeliverCreatedTime 
FROM `Jobs`
GROUP BY `Order_ID`
```

Comment: Hi Dnoeth, thank you, this is what I needed, except I had to change Min to Max as when there was no value the Min was 0.